# PHP file upload - dropdown subfolder selection

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm building a simple upload portal for my office. I have successfully coded it to pass the uploaded items into a folder named /uploads, however I would like to add a dropdown to select between a number of subfolders so people can better organize the stuff that is in there.

This is my HTML

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label for="file">Filename:</label>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
            <select name="Folder">
                <option value="OurPhoto">Our Photos</option>
                <option value="StockPhoto">Stock Photos</option>
                <option value="Video">Videos</option>
                <option value="Document">Documents</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my PHP for upload.php

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
        echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
    }
    else {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    }
}
```

My subfolders are named MCPhoto, StockPhoto, Video, Documents and Other.
My PHP knowledge is kind of weak so I don't really know where to go from here..

Comment: Do **NOT** use this code. You are opening your door to a COMPLETE remote server compromise by allowing your users to scribble a file ANYWHERE on your server, with a name of THEIR choosing.

Comment: What would you suggest then? I have the directory password protected, so in order to even access it you need to have the login/psw that was set through cpanel and also the password that is set within access.php

Comment: at least scrub the HELL out of the `['name']` parameter. That's completely under user control, and can include pathing information. You're at least checking for duplicate uploads, but consider what could happen if `['name'] = /etc/passwd`, or `c:\windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe`. You should also be limiting the allowable file types, and **NOT** put them in a place where they can be reached by direct url.

Comment: Well, I'm not too worried about people within my company uploading anything nasty. I'm more worried that someone would gain access to the index.php and upload stuff that are not part of the company, however like I have said I set a password through access.php and also a username/psw on the directory as set through cpanel.

Comment: never assume coworkers are trustworthy, or that a username/password won't be left on a post-it in a public place. all it takes is one person on a bad hair day to make your life miserable.

Comment: You have a point, I will have to do a great deal of research because my knowledge of PHP is pretty low.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to get the value of the Folder field from the `$_POST` variable and include it in your upload code.

```
if (file_exists("upload/".$_POST["Folder"] . "/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $_POST["Folder"] . "/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_POST["Folder"] . "/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
$folder = $_POST['Folder'];

// sanitise $folder

$location = 'upload/' . rtrim($folder, '/') . '/' . $_FILES['file']['name'];

if(file_exists($location)) {
    echo $_FILES['file']['name'] . ' already exists.';
}
else {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],  $location);
    echo 'Stored in: ' . $location;
}
```

Make absolutely sure the `Folder` input is safe before using it in the `$location`.

Comment: Making sure the folders already exists. Otherwise, the OP would need to add a `mkdir` directive.

Comment: Sanitising `$folder` should disallow writing to a folder that doesn't exist - that's one of its purposes.

Answer (score 0):

This code has way too many security holes.  I am trying to help you when I say you should do a lot more research before attempting this.

Please at least read:http://blog.insicdesigns.com/2009/01/secure-file-upload-in-php-web-applications/

You may want to hire a professional because your server's security is at risk.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do here..

since you want to store the files into the subfolders of your choice you need to first get the name of subfolder by using

```
   $_POST['folder']
```

or

```
  $GLOBALS['_POST']['folder']
```

and then store into a variable like $loc and then you can add the codes in this manner

```
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"upload/" .$loc."/". $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

Pretty new with this site so I am not familiar with how to show codes in a good manner...

Hope it will help you